# Best practice to handle memory leak for Static Field in C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, static-members

I am supposed to create a context object for the current instance of the user, and the code is

```
 public class WorkoutContext {
    protected static WorkoutContext mWorkoutContext ;
    protected WorkOut mWorkOut;

    protected WorkoutContext(WorkOut workout)
    {
        mWorkOut= workout;
    }

    public static WorkoutContext CreateContext(WorkOut workout))
    {
        if (mWorkoutContext == null)
        {
            mWorkoutContext = new WorkoutContext (form);
        }
        else
        {
            if (workout != mWorkoutContext.WorkOut)
            {
                mWorkoutContext = new WorkoutContext (workout);
            }
        }
        return mWorkoutContext ;
    }
 }
```

In concurrent environment, for each user it is creating an instance for `WorkOutContext` but not release the instance after the request process completion. To Overcome this issue modified the `CreateContext` method as follow

```
public class WorkoutContext {
   protected WorkoutContext mWorkoutContext ;
   protected WorkOut mWorkOut;

   protected WorkoutContext(WorkOut workout)
   {
        mWorkOut= workout;
   }

   public static WorkoutContext CreateContext(WorkOut workout))
   {       
       return new WorkoutContext(workout);
   }
}
```

Is there any other way to implement to have only one instance of `WorkoutContext` for the same `WorkOut` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public class WorkoutContext {
    protected WorkOut mWorkOut;
    private static Dictionary<WorkOut, WorkoutContext> dic = new ...;
    private static object lockObj = new object();

    protected WorkoutContext(WorkOut workout)
    {
         mWorkOut= workout;
    }

    public static WorkoutContext CreateContext(WorkOut workout)
    {   
        lock(lockObj) {
             if (dic.ContainsKey(workout))
                  return dic[workout];
             var wc = new WorkoutContext(workout)
             dic.Add(workout, wc);
             return wc;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The proposed way will hold the object instance in Dictionary, how frequently we can delete the instance after the user completion his process. Ex. In Windsor there is lifestyle to hold the object instance update to the request completed.(PerWebRequestLifeStyle) is it possible to overcome this scenario with Windsor castle.